# Как можно добавить элемент вниз div чтобы была возможность скролла?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Как можно добавить элемент **span**(допустим), вниз div, чтобы была возможность скролла когда элементов **span** станет много?

Если я добавляю через свойство absolute, то скролл просто не работает. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, список должен пополняться, элементы прилипать снизу один за другим. Вообще, HTML так не работает, однако даже без использования хитрых флексов и скриптов, можно "повернуть" контейнер и его контент на 180 градусов, относительно друг-друга:

```
.rolled-container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.rolled-container, .rolled-container > .inner-div {
  -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

Это самое простое кроссбраузерное решение без скриптов.

Comment: Спасибо! Если не ошибаюсь, то ползунок скролла будет с левой стороны. в IE8 работать не будет и в operamini, тоже. А так, по моему хорошо)

Comment: да, впрочем, решение на скриптах в operamini тоже будет проблемным. В мозиле скролл остаётся где должен, но скроллится в обратную, конечно. :)